# Paginating with ajax (jquery) - big database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Is it smart to use ajax pagination for bulk databases?

I have that cool fast jquery live search filter, but i am afraid i wont be able to use it with PHP pagination since (as far as i know) page content is generated (selected from database) every time you go to next page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use Memcache ( http://memcached.org/ ) for caching search results in server's memory. In that case next time particular page is requested you will retrieve it without querying the database.